# Deploying Liferay project

Tags: java, liferay

I faced with a problem which I can not solve it.

- I have created a **Liferay Plugin Project** and developed my personal
  portlet. In addition, I wrote some **JSP TagLibs** which I have imported to
  my `view.jsp` of portlet.
- Tag lib files are placed in `WEB-INF/tags` project's folder. At
  first, project is deployed normally, while some problems are raised
  in successor deploys. In fact, in this phase, project deploys
  normally but when I want to review the result in browser, an
  exception is introduced (The content of exception is mentioned in the
  end of this message).
- Besides, I found a solution for this problem, but I know that this is
  not a standard and logical solution. If I delete `war` file from
  `liferay\osgi\war`, project related file from
  `liferay\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi` folder  and `<project-name>`
  folder form `liferay\work`, the mentioned problem is erased.
- I'm using Liferay 7, Ant builder, Eclipse Mars X64, Java 8 x64 and 
  win 7 X64.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:261] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__ [Sanitized]
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /html/reportViewer/reportDefinition/view.jsp_PWC6199: Generated servlet error:_package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.base does not exist__ [Sanitized]
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
>       at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:399)
>       at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:410)
>       at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
>       at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:252)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:102)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:556)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:572)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doView(MVCPortlet.java:157)
>       at org.samfad.base.controller.BaseController.doView(BaseController.java:107)
>       at org.samfad.report.reportViewer.controller.ReportDefinitionController.doView(ReportDefinitionController.java:70)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:302)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:471)
>       at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.render(MVCPortlet.java:291)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
>           .
>           . 
>           .
>           .

Comment: Looks like your taglib file is having some compilation issues.

Comment: Does your tag(s) have attribute declarations or use jstl tags? And second question is do you have your tld file for your tag(s)?

Comment: Dear Martin, My TagLibs are _attribute declaration_. Indeed, I have used programming style which mentioned in the below link for TagLibs. [link](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jserverpages3_ch11/index.html)

Comment: Please add code from your tag file

Answer (score 0):

Step to fix:-

1.Go to Lib folder of Liferay Tomcat .
2.Replace :- ecj-3.7.2.jar with  ecj-4.4.2.
3.Restart the Server.